# Как приближенно вычислить значение числа Пи с использованием объема сферы?

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, монте-карло

Моя задача - вычислить приближенное значение числа Пи с точностью не менее 10^-6. Алгоритм Монте-Карло не обеспечивает требуемой точности. Мне нужно использовать расчет с использованием объема шара. Что посоветуете?

Comment: А чем вас Монте-Карло не устраивает собственно? Уточните.

Comment: Попробуйте ряд Нилаканта. и уточните что там про шар ? какие данные есть ?

Comment: Если критично именно сферу использовать - просто тремя циклами проходите по координатам от 0 до R, проверяйте попадает ли координата внутрь сферы. Но тогда не не будет постепенного приближения к точному значению, а нужно будет дождаться до конца выполнения всех циклов, и только потом получить результат.

Comment: @Kromster Эффективность алгоритма мизерная, если мы говорим о точности до 6 знаков. Алгоритм Монте-Карло эффективен только до 4-5 знаков после запятой - проверено. Вдобавок точность сильно варьируется из-за случайной природы значений x, y, z, из-за чего одно и то же количество итераций выдает абсолютно разные результаты после первого и второго запуска

Comment: @Интик данных как таковых нет, пусть радиус сферы равен 1 - это единственное, что нам известно. Нам нужно найти объем сферы, а оттуда и Пи

Comment: @Asan Монте-Карло (да и любой другой алгоритм перебора) надо запускать и оставлять не до того момента, как он впервые покажет 3,141592**, а дольше. Насколько точно дольше - не подскажу, тут надо теорию вспоминать/знать ..

Comment: Посоветую численное интегрирование для вычисления объема шара.

Answer (score 0):

Приблизим осьмушку шара треугольным мешем. Вершины меша будут лежать на поверхности единичной сферы. Тело ограниченное координатными плоскостями и мешем лежит целиком внутри осьмушки шара. Его объём используем для оценки `pi` снизу. Отыщем множитель на который нужно умножить координаты всех вершин меша так чтобы после умножения фигура содержала осьмушку шара внутри себя. Объём новой (раздутой) фигуры используем для оценки `pi` сверху. Так как мы не знаем заранее сколько должно быть треугольников в меше, то будем повторять процедуру со всё более подробными мешами пока оценки `pi` не сблизятся на расстояние 10^-6. Поехали.

Четыре поколения поверхностей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начинается всё с одного треугольника. Следующая поверхность строится так: каждый треугольник предыдущей разбивается на четыре меньшего размера. Новые точки на серединах сторон оказываются под поверхностью сферы. Чтобы вернуть их на сферу их координаты нормализуются.

Объём полигонального тела складывается из объёмов тетраэдров. Тетраэдр строится на треугольнике поверхности и точке `(0, 0, 0)`. Шестикратный объём такого тетраэдра вычисляется как определитель.

Имеем последовательность оценок числа `pi` снизу. Как оценить `pi` сверху?

Каждый треугольник поверхности определяет плоскость. Вычислим минимальное расстояние от этой плоскости до начала координат: строим единичный нормальный вектор к треугольнику, скалярно умножаем его на координаты любой вершины треугольника. Расстояние получится меньше единицы.

Если все координаты всех вершин треугольника умножить на величину обратную к найденному расстоянию, то новые вершины образуют новую плоскость (параллельную старой), для которой расстояние будет единичным.

Выберем минимум из расстояний для всех треугольников поверхности. Все вершины поверхности домножим на обратную величину. Получим новую поверхность гомотетичную старой. Новая поверхность целиком проходит вне шара. То есть объём нового тела будет больше `pi`. Конечно, суммировать его заново не надо, он вычисляется из объёма поверхности внутри шара умножением на некоторый коэффициент.

Код:

```
import math


def add(p1, p2):
    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2
    return x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2


def sub(p1, p2):
    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2
    return x1 - x2, y1 - y2, z1 - z2


def scale(f, p):
    x, y, z = p
    return f * x, f * y, f * z


def mid(p1, p2):
    return scale(1 / 2, add(p1, p2))


def dot(p1, p2):
    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2
    return x1 * x2 + y1 * y2 + z1 * z2


def norm(p):
    return math.sqrt(dot(p, p))


def normalized(p):
    return scale(1 / norm(p), p)


def cross(p1, p2):
    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2
    return \
        y1 * z2 - z1 * y2, \
        z1 * x2 - x1 * z2, \
        x1 * y2 - y1 * x2


def normal(p1, p2, p3):
    return normalized(cross(sub(p2, p1), sub(p3, p1)))


def height(p1, p2, p3):
    return dot(normal(p1, p2, p3), p1)


def volume6(p1, p2, p3):
    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2
    x3, y3, z3 = p3
    # | x1, y1, z1 |
    # | x2, y2, z2 |
    # | x3, y3, z3 |
    return \
        ((x1 * y2) - (x2 * y1)) * z3 - \
        ((x1 * y3) - (x3 * y1)) * z2 + \
        ((x2 * y3) - (x3 * y2)) * z1


def subdiv(p1, p2, p3):
    p12 = normalized(mid(p1, p2))
    p23 = normalized(mid(p2, p3))
    p31 = normalized(mid(p3, p1))
    yield p1, p12, p31
    yield p2, p23, p12
    yield p3, p31, p23
    yield p12, p23, p31


def main():
    surface = (((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), )
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        print(f'{i}({len(surface)}): ', flush=True, end='')
        min_height = min(height(*t) for t in surface)
        v_low = sum(volume6(*t) for t in surface)
        v_high = v_low * (1 / min_height) ** 3
        print(f'{v_low} < pi < {v_high}, {v_high - v_low}')
        if v_high - v_low < 1e-6:
            break
        surface = tuple(tt for t in surface for tt in subdiv(*t))


main()
```

> ```
> $ time python pi_approximation.py 
> 1(1): 1 < pi < 5.196152422706629, 4.196152422706629
> 2(4): 2.207106781186547 < pi < 4.054714066307733, 1.8476072851211862
> 3(16): 2.8632972148712703 < pi < 3.4166084802548, 0.5533112653835297
> 4(64): 3.0687004650644996 < pi < 3.2136638054952016, 0.14496334043070203
> 5(256): 3.123152697186476 < pi < 3.1598235333433777, 0.03667083615690192
> 6(1024): 3.136968953405614 < pi < 3.1461637781466827, 0.009194824741068697
> 7(4096): 3.140435869168335 < pi < 3.142736273849948, 0.0023004046816126333
> 8(16384): 3.1413034037353573 < pi < 3.141878611120626, 0.0005752073852685058
> 9(65536): 3.141520337766175 < pi < 3.1416641462518413, 0.00014380848566641902
> 10(262144): 3.1415745744239363 < pi < 3.141610526960324, 3.595253638755125e-05
> 11(1048576): 3.1415881337850373 < pi < 3.141597121945071, 8.988160033585046e-06
> 12(4194304): 3.141591523637882 < pi < 3.141593770679511, 2.2470416292108553e-06
> 13(16777216): 3.141592371100547 < pi < 3.1415929328610557, 5.617605087770983e-07
>
> real  2m59.102s
> user  2m57.320s
> sys   0m1.480s
> ```

Comment: Может быть путаю, а не достаточно одного треугольника внутри/вне с рекурсивным уменьшением его размера? 16млн идентичных - как-то многовато ..

Comment: Они не идентичные. Я не умею составлять поверхность сферы из одинаковых треугольников. Подозреваю, что никто не умеет.